# Вывод значений произвольных полей ACF указанных в карточке товара woocommerce в письме customer completed_order

Tags: woocommerce, acf

знающие люди.
Создал произвольные поля с помощью ACF, вывел их через шаблон в конструкторе темы в карточках товаров.
Теперь нужно вывести значения конкретных произвольных полей заполненных в карточке товара woocommerce в письме `customer_completed_order` после завершения покупки.
Зарегистрировал через сниппет экшен:

```
add_action('personalnye_dannye', 'action_function')
function action_function() {
    echo (get_post_meta($post->355, 'key' => 'field_5ec5a4cd49fe1', true));
}
```

В шаблоне customer_completed_order вставил: `do_action('personalnye_dannye');`
Что не так????

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос, что именно не работает или работает, но не так? Есть ли какая-либо ошибка?

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос, что именно не работает или работает, но не так? Есть ли какая-либо ошибка? – Сергей Маяк. Не выводится ничего...